# Where is official Android sample app tictactoe reciever code (html) located?

Tags: android, google-cast

I would expect, that folder receiver with tictactoe reciever source code (html) is in example folder: .../sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/samples/cast/tictactoe/src/com/google/android/gms/cast/samples/tictactoe!

Where is official example tictactoe reciever chromecast source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They recently added it to their github.

[googlecast/tictactoe-receiver](https://github.com/googlecast/tictactoe-receiver)

Comment: Yes! I have reported issue on google-cast, and they fixed issue in few hours ;) Good work cast-team!

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking the same thing as I scrolled through all the github entries and did not see it.  I see references to it on the web and I get a 404 from Git when I try them.

I think this is a fork or a copy of some sort but it might be enough to get you started.
https://github.com/angrygorilla/cast-android-tictactoe

Comment: Thanks, I have also found that, but i think this is fork on deprecated version of example. Quick look on GameActivity: public class GameActivity extends ActionBarActivity original and on git public class GameActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements MediaRouteAdapter! Maybe this version doesn't need receiver code.